# WSDL desde HTML con VBSCript

Tags: html, webservice, wcf, vbscript

¿Alguien sabe como puedo consumir un servicio Web WSDL desde una página HTML por medio de VBSCript? Tengo que enviar un String por parámetro y recibir un objeto de vuelta, he encontrado ejemplos pero ninguno me funciona

Comment: Podrias dejar los codigos que has probado y ver porque no funcionan

Comment: MI función es DesencriptarDatos, Mi servicio es http://192.168.0.124/WcfCRSol_DesencriptarDoc/Desencriptar.svc, El Método para desencriptar es Leer_Datos_String que recibe como parámetro un String, Y me devuelve un objeto, con este código el strResult = ""